# In an Excel UserForm, how do I update a label's caption?

Tags: excel, vba, label, caption, userform

I created my first modeless **`UserForm`** in Excel and put an ActiveX label on it.  How do I set the caption of the label so that it displays whatever is in `Sheet1.Range("A1")`, and updates itself when the value in cell A1 changes?

Basically, I want the **`Userform's`** label to always be updated the second anything in the Excel cell changes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Cells(1, 1), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

The sub `Change` gets called everytime a cell changes. The code does this: if `A1` was changed, change the caption of `Label1` on `UserForm1`. The form must have been opened not modal (`vbModeless`).

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

Comment: Hi cularis, thanks for the amazingly fast response!  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me.

```
Sheets("Sheet").Shapes("TheNameOfTheLabel").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello"
```