# How to execute code after userform is opened?

Tags: excel, vba

I hope this question is not too trivial as I am new to VBA.

I want to make a label in a userform show data from a cell on a worksheet. The label should show this data directly when the userform opens.

This thread probably gives me the answer:

[In an Excel UserForm, how do I update a label's caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858747/in-an-excel-userform-how-do-i-update-a-labels-caption#)

However I am confused regarding WHERE to put this code?!

Should I put it into the Userform directly?
-> this would make the most sense to me but does not work, as the code is not even executed then.
Should I create a new module for this code?
-> then how do I call this sub automatically after the userform opens?

Thanks alot in advance!
Leo

Comment: When do you want the userform to open? When you enter a value in a cell?

Comment: No. The Userform opens, once a specific button on a previously shown userform is clicked.

Comment: So you have 2 Userforms? The first one shows and there is a button on it and if you click it, it will show Form2?  In that case `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Form2.label1.caption = CellValue 
 form2.show
End Sub` In this case you just need to reference the cell correctly and you should get the value. Give it a go and show us what you have tried, the code and if you get stuck we can help you.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment answer here so this post can be marked as answered.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
 Form2.label1.caption = CellValue 
 form2.show 
End Sub
```